# Probability of drawing one spade AND one of either 10,9 or 8

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In a game of Open Face Chinese poker, I encounter this problem quite often.

One draws three cards at a time and one of these cards must be discarded, so two of three drawn cards can be used.

A typical problem and question in this game would be:

**What is the probability of drawing one spade AND one of either 10,9 or 8 (call it Middle cards) with drawing three cards?**

We could have 10,9,8 of spades but we will need either another spade or another of the same group the draw to be successful.

My approach was following - Success scenarios:

1. Spade and Middle Card - 13/52*10/51
2. Spade and Middle Spade 10/52*3/51
3. Middle and Middle Spade 9/52*3/51
4. Middle Spade and Middle Spade 3/52*2/51

But this is for drawing 2 cards, how shall I input the third card drawing possibility into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I find it a little easier to calculate the probability of failing to get what you want; then you can subtract that from $1$ to get the desired probability. You fail if you draw no spade or no middle card. There are $\binom{39}3$ ways to draw three non-spades, and there are $\binom{40}3$ ways to draw no middle card. However, some sets of three cards have been counted twice, because they contain neither a spade nor a middle card. There are $13$ spades and $9$ non-spade middle cards, so there are $30$ cards that are neither spades nor middle cards and therefore $\binom{30}3$ sets of three cards that are ‘bad’ in both ways. Altogether, then, there are

$$\binom{39}3+\binom{40}3-\binom{30}3$$

bad draws out of the total of $\binom{52}3$ possible draws, and the desired probability is

$$1-\frac{\binom{39}3+\binom{40}3-\binom{30}3}{\binom{52}3}\;,$$

which is a little less than $\frac13$.

Comment: Appreaciate your taking time to answer, I have favoured the same principle as soon as "at least one" kicks in in the terms of a task, prefer to calculate the chances of missing the favourable outcome. Still, I couldn't get my head around the problem where I had intersection between the sets. Could you please explain more about the third number in the equation (30,3). Still cannot figure out how to arrive to that thought of subtracting this number. Is that because we counted some cards twice and this subtraction takes care of that excess?

Comment: @SKYTTEN: You're welcome. Yes, it is. Every set of three cards that contains no spades *and* no middle cards is counted once in the $\binom{39}3$ and once again in the $\binom{40}3$. There are $\binom{30}3$ such sets, and every one of them has been counted twice in the sum $\binom{39}3+\binom{40}3$. In order to compensate, we must subtract $1$ for each of those sets that we've counted twice. This means subtracting $\binom{30}3$.